# Do retained fragments work when activity is recreated due to configuration change only?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to retain a fragment not only when activity is recreated due to configuration change, but also in cases when it's just, you know, recreated for some other reason, like when user has left it and returned back a second later. Apparently, it doesn't work, because in the following code

```
homeMapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(homeMapFragmentTag);
if(homeMapFragment == null) {
    homeMapFragment = new MapFragment();
    homeMapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_fragment_placeholder, homeMapFragment, homeMapFragmentTag).commit();
}
```

execution always enters the `if` branch. Is it a lost cause, or there is something else I can do here?

Clarification: this fragment is actually visible. My intention is not to retain some data between the different activities, but to retain the view itself. It's a map view, and it takes some time to initialize the map, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently, it doesn't work

That is because retained fragments are only retained for configuration changes, not other events.

`onSaveInstanceState()` covers more scenarios (e.g., user presses HOME, your process gets terminated a bit later, then the user returns to your app via the recent-tasks list).

However, even that does not cover what you seem to be describing: user presses BACK, then presses something that would return them to the same activity that they left. In that case, from Android's standpoint, those are two logically distinct activity instances and are not really related. If you want to hold onto data between them, that's best handled by a backing store (e.g., database, `SharedPreferences`, or other file), optionally with some in-memory cache to save on I/O time.